# Filter features shown by date in Qfield

Tags: filter, qfield

I'm trying to set up qfield for tree inspections. I know you can filter features in QGIS, but does it carry over to QField?

For instance, I have many trees, but I only want the ones with overdue/upcoming inspection dates to show up on Qfield and for this to update itself without having to do it through QGIS.

So if I had a filter along the lines of "only show features (trees) with "next_inspection" > [now+1 month]” (I know that's not a valid filter, it's just to clarify) would the filter update itself on Qfield as new trees enter the date range?

Is it possible to filter features at all on Qfield?

I'm still new to this so I'm simultaneously trying to learn the basics while also trying to get the more complex features I actually need working.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  It emphasizes that there should be only one question asked per question.  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question for GIS SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a tree consultant myself I question whether you really want to hide all trees not due for inspection. Seeing other nearby trees in QField helps the surveyor navigate to the correct tree. I would recommend showing all trees, but use rule-based styling to theme them differently. You can apply different colours, symbol, size etc to those due for inspection and those that are not.

For the first rule you can filter the trees due for inspection using the age() function. It returns the interval between two dates. YOu can force the interval to be days by nesting it inside the day() function. You can then use the BETWEEN operator to define the range of dates.

For the second rule, use ELSE, to catch all others.

Fig 1. Rule-based Styling, with two rules, one for all trees that are due, the other for all other
[image]

Fig 2. The rule for trees that are due. Replace 'datetime' with your inspection due date.
[image]

Fig.3 The rule for all others.
[image]

Comment: It's an in-house inspection team and we have an drone orthophoto of the site so the idea is to hide up to date trees to reduce clutter. I've found out that layer filters don't update on Qfield, so as you say it'll be better to use rule based symbol/labels to visually highlight trees due for inspections. I'll give what you've suggested a try. Thanks.

Comment: For trees NOT due for inspection you can of course turn off visiblility for the relevant symbology.